# How to configure Skype to mute media players when in a call?

Tags: windows, audio, skype, media-player, mute

I have heard that Skype can mute other programs during calls. I would like to configure it to do so automatically.

I use Windows XP and Foobar2000

Comment: It does so for me out of the box.

Comment: @Johannes Do you use Windows XP and Foobar2000?

Comment: No. Since you edited that in merely six hours ago, I assumed Windows 7 and it's a Windows feature that Skype simply taps into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way I've found to do this on Windows is by going into Sound, under control panel (Control panel -> Sound) and then click on the "Communications" tab. There, you should see an option to "Mute All Other Sounds" during a call. This actually works with Skype 4.0+.

Comment: which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: These options continue to be available in "Control Panel > Sound" in Windows 10